# What is the exact value of $\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{5/2}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, closed-form

> I would like  to get the exact value of the following integral.
>   $$\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{5/2}}\,dx$$

I was able to prove the convergence as well. But I don't how to compute its exact value. I tried with the Residue Theorem of the complex function

$$z\mapsto \frac{\sin^2 z}{z^{5/2}}$$
But I could not move further.

Comment: Hmm this [integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) shows that it is divergent?

Comment: @aleden: that integral calculator sucks. The given function behaves like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin and it is bounded by $\frac{1}{x^2}$ far from the origin, hence it is integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ah I see

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I hate it when people say “this integral calculator evaluates your integral to be ...”

Comment: me too. with calculator every thing becomes banal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a step of integration by parts the problem boils down to computing

$$ \frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x^{3/2}}\,dx =\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{3/2}}\,dx\stackrel{\mathcal{L},\mathcal{L}^{-1}}{=}\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{s}}{s^2+1}\,ds$$
and the last integral is elementary (just enforce the substitution $s\mapsto u^2$ and perform a partial fraction decomposition). By the properties of [the Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis), the final outcome is  $\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{\pi}$.

Answer (score 2):

Performing the change of variables $2u = x^2$ together with two integration by parts, we get, $$ \int_0^\infty \cos(x^2)dx =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int^\infty_0\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx\\=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\underbrace{\left[\frac{\sin 2 x}{x^{1/2}}\right]_0^\infty}_{=0} +\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} \int^\infty_0\frac{\sin 2 x}{x^{3/2}}\,dx\\=
 \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\underbrace{\left[\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{1/2}}\right]_0^\infty}_{=0} +\frac{3}{8\sqrt{2}} \int^\infty_0\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{5/2}}\,dx$$

Hence $$\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{5/2}}\,dx = \frac{8\sqrt2}{3}\int_0^\infty \cos(x^2)dx = \frac{4\sqrt \pi}{3}$$
Since [See Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2507570),  $$\int_0^\infty \cos(x^2)dx= \sqrt\frac\pi8$$

or
[How to prove only by Transformation that: $ \int_0^\infty \cos(x^2) dx = \int_0^\infty \sin(x^2) dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498628/how-to-prove-only-by-transformation-that-int-0-infty-cosx2-dx-int-0?noredirect=1#comment5174905_2498628)

Answer (score 1):

This integral $I$ can be interpreted as the Mellin transform of $\sin(x)^2$ evaluated at $s=-3/2$.
$$
\mathcal{M}[\sin(x)^2] = -2^{-1-s}\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma(s)
$$
so
$$
I = \Gamma\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right) = \frac{4\sqrt{\pi}}{3}
$$