# How do I prove the relation: $\intop_{t=0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt=2\sqrt{2}\intop_{x=0}^{+\infty}{\sin(x^2)}dx$

Tags: integration, gamma-function, gaussian-integral

I want to prove the following relation:
$${\Gamma_{1/2}}=\intop_{t=0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt=2\sqrt{2}\intop_{x=0}^{+\infty}{\sin(x^2)}dx$$

I noticed that: $$\frac{\intop_{x=-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{-x^2}}dt}{\sqrt{2}}=\intop_{x=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\sin(x^2)}dx=\intop_{x=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\cos(x^2)}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

And consequently proved the relation by comparing the resulting value. However, I would like to know any alternate solutions that do not include the Gaussian integral. I have had no luck figuring this out, I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: See [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/251120/695) answers your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the idea from Quanto in this post ([Proof only by transformation that : $ \int_0^\infty \cos(x^2) dx = \int_0^\infty \sin(x^2) dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498628/proof-only-by-transformation-that-int-0-infty-cosx2-dx-int-0-infty)). Note
$$ \frac1{\sqrt2}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}dx, \int_0^\infty\sin(x^2)dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}dx. $$
Let
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt2}2e^{-x}-\sin x, g(x)=\frac1{\sqrt x}$$
and then
$$ \mathcal{L}\{f\}(x)=\frac1{\sqrt2(x+1)}-\frac1{x^2+1}, \mathcal{L}\{g\}(x)=\sqrt{\frac\pi x}. $$
Now using
$$ \int_0^\infty\mathcal{L} \{g\}(x)f(x)dx = \int_0^\infty g(x)\mathcal{L}\{f\}(x)dx $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac1{\sqrt2}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx-\int_0^\infty\sin(x^2)dx\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)dx=\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty f(x)\mathcal{L}\{g\}(x)dx\\
&=&\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty g(x)\mathcal{L}\{f\}(x)dx\\
&=&\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac1{\sqrt x}\bigg(\frac1{\sqrt2(x+1)}-\frac1{x^2+1}\bigg)dx\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray}
So
$$ \frac1{\sqrt2}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty\sin(x^2)dx. $$